# Replace specific string in ArrayList with random string from another ArrayList

Tags: java, string, file, arraylist, filereader

Im fairly new in programming java (just started a couple of months ago) and i am unfortunatly in a bit of confused state at the moment.

I am presently using BlueJ for my programming, and ive encountered a exercise in in my book which i do have some problems getting the grips of how to further add the wanted functionality.

The exercise has two previously made classes (ReaderInput & WriterOutput), and i am to create a new class which calls and makes use of the preceeding classes methods. The exercise includes two .txt files, one includes a story, and the second one includes differents kinds of adjectives(words). Then, i have to read the story.txt file, and replace Strings in that file with a specific value(a string with the value "ADJECTIVE"), with randomly chosen words from the adjectives.txt file, and finally, output them (write) to a completely new file.

A sample from the story.txt file:

'Once upon a time there was a ADJECTIVE girl who were in a ADJECTIVE birthday togheter with lots of ADJECTIVE friends etc....'

A sample from the adjectives.txt file:

whiny
old
little
stupid
etc...

So, i created a new class, added and initialized new field objects of the ReaderInput class, like so;

```
private ReaderInput reader;
private WriterOutput writer;
private Random random;

public StoryCreator()
{
    reader = new ReaderInput();
    writer = new WriterOutput();
    random = new Random();
}
```

Then i created a new method called createAdjectiveStory with parameters to specify both the story filename and adjectives.

```
public void createAdjectiveStory(String storyFilename, String adjectivesFilename/*, String outputFilename*/)
```

Then, i declare two variables to hold the reader words from the ReaderInput class(specifying the file to read through parameters):

```
    ArrayList<String> story = reader.getWordsInFile(storyFilename);

    ArrayList<String> adjective = reader.getWordsInFile(adjectivesFilename);
```

Then here comes the big headache. While, i have been able to declare a String varible wordToChange = "ADJECTIVE"; , create a for-each loop to iterate over the story arraylist collection, with an if statement to check if string in element is equal to wordToChange. At last i made a random to go trough the adjective arryalist, and get a random word from the collection (This gets a random word from the file each time i call the method and print it individually)

```
for(String reader : story){

        int index = random.nextInt(adjective.size());
        String word = adjective.get(index);

        if(reader.equals(wordToChange))

            Collections.replaceAll(story,wordToChange,word); 

        }
    }
```

In the if statement, i tried to use the replaceAll function, like so:

```
Collections.replaceAll(story,wordToChange,word);
```

The problem here is that if i try to print this out (just to verify that it works), i get this:

'Once upon a time there was a OLD girl who were in a OLD birthday togheter with lots of OLD friends etc....'

Now i rather want this.

'Once upon a time there was a OLD girl who were in a WHINY borthday togheter with lots of STUPID friends etc....'

Ive tried make use of the .replace function, like so:

```
Collections.replace(story,wordToChange,word);
```

But i get an error specifying: 'Cannot find symbol - method replace'.

I am quite stuck right about here, and i cannot seem to find the right solution for this. Ayone have any tips/tricks or solution for this?

New programmer needing a little "push" in the right direction. Any help will be appreciated highly:)

Comment: The error you are getting is because [`Collections.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is not a valid method

Comment: You have a conceptual problem here.  The words to replace, the ADJECTIVES, requires two words: the old word and the new word.  Where are those coming from?  As a `List` you only have one word.  I'd check with your instructor as to the format of that second file, it likely has two words per line or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's choosing the word to change it to once and then the replaceAll is replacing every instance of REPLACE immediately.

What you should do instead is use an iterator in your for loop:

```
Iterator<String> i=story.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String check = i.next();
    if (check.equals(stringToReplace)) {
        i.set(getRandomAdjective());
    }
}
```

You should create a method for your code to get a random adjective.

Comment: Thanks Tim B! Working beautifully now :)